# How to get all the values against a particular tag in webpage

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Is there any way to get all the values displaying against "BRAND" .

I want to store all the value that will display for the BRAND and sore those value in the collection so that I can compare with one more collection and find which value will get match in between those.

below is the screenshot . Please give some input .

[image]

Comment: You could look for the xpath td[contains(text(),'Brand')}//following::td and then .getText().

Comment: i have written  the below code using the below x-path ;

 public void assert_details()
{
    List<WebElement> names= driver.findElements(By.xpath("//td[contains(text(),'Brand')]//following::td"));

    for(int i=0; i<names.size();i++)
    {
        System.out.println("the brand associated with the BRAND is -- "+names.get(i).getText());
    }

and the out put is :
the brand associated with the BRAND is -- IZOD
the brand associated with the BRAND is -- Season:
the brand associated with the BRAND is -- Spring 2020 .  
the value only associated with the BRAND [i.e :IZOD]

Comment: What website is it on?

Comment: ok .. that my client portal

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest way:

```
List<String> brands = new ArrayList<String>();
List<WebElement> fields = driver.findElements(By.className("asset-page__field-value"));
for (WebElement field: fields) {
    brands.add(field.getText());
}
```